# postgres: can't drop database which appears in list

Tags: postgresql, psql

In psql (as user postgres in the postgres database) the command `\list` shows:

```
postgres=# \list
                                                  List of databases
     Name      |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |   Access privileges   
---------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------
 dummy         | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc              | 
 italo         | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 magnus2_2022  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 magnus2_2023  | magnus   | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 magnus2_2024B | magnus   | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 magnus2_2024C | magnus   | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 magnus2_2024D | magnus   | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 magnus2_2024E | magnus   | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 magnus2_2024F | magnus   | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 magnus2_2024G | magnus   | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 magnus2_2024H | magnus   | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 magnus2_2024J | magnus   | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 magnus2_2024K | magnus   | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 magnus2_2024L | magnus   | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 postgres      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | 
 template0     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
               |          |          |            |            |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
               |          |          |            |            |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
(17 rows)
```

Some of these databases can't be renamed or deleted:

```
postgres=# alter database magnus2_2024K rename to magnus2_2024X;
ERROR:  database "magnus2_2024k" does not exist
postgres=# drop database magnus2_2024k;
ERROR:  database "magnus2_2024k" does not exist
postgres=#
```

On the other hand i can open these databases with `psql` and perform `SELECT`s:

```
 $ psql -U magnus magnus2_2024K
psql (15.4, server 14.9)
Type "help" for help.

magnus2_2024K=> \d
                 List of relations
 Schema |         Name          |   Type   | Owner  
--------+-----------------------+----------+--------
 public | accounts              | table    | magnus
 public | constants             | table    | magnus
 public | constants_comment_seq | sequence | magnus
 public | constants_id_seq      | sequence | magnus
 public | dummy                 | table    | magnus
 public | fixed_accounts        | table    | magnus
 public | flat                  | table    | magnus
 public | flat_id_seq           | sequence | magnus
 public | flat_rent             | table    | magnus
 public | lodger                | table    | magnus
 public | lodger_id_seq         | sequence | magnus
 public | lodger_mode           | table    | magnus
 public | rent_item             | table    | magnus
 public | rent_item_id_seq      | sequence | magnus
 public | trans_group_seq       | sequence | magnus
 public | transaction_groups    | table    | magnus
 public | transaction_types     | table    | magnus
 public | transactions          | table    | magnus
 public | transactions_id_seq   | sequence | magnus
 public | types                 | table    | magnus
(20 rows)

magnus2_2024K=> select * from constants where name like '%rate';
 id |   name    | value | comment 
----+-----------+-------+---------
 15 | rep_rate  | 1.05  | SFr/m2
 14 | nkhk_rate | 1.92  | SFr/m2
  8 | solirate  | 0.35  | SFr/m2
(3 rows)
```

How can i delete a database (such as `magnus2_2024K`) which appears on the list but can't be deleted beause it allegedly does not existwith

Comment: What happens if you do `select * from pg_database where datname = 'magnus2_2024K'`

Comment: I get an ordinary output, identical to the output for one of the 'normal' dbs (with exception of the oid)

Comment: I need new glasses, I missed the mixed case.  The statement should be `alter database "magnus2_2024K" rename to "magnus2_2024X";` . See [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) for why.